# Using WAMP for web purposes?

Tags: wamp, self-hosting

So we all know that with wamp we can create dummy domains to test scripts on for example `mysite.imo` instead of using localhost. Can I use this function to allow people to connect to `mysite.imo` instead of what ever my ip is.. So in other words can I host my own custom domain with wamp instead of buying into a domain or using my ip to get traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not as simple as that.

You can, however, provide your *computer's name* to people on your local network, and they can use that to connect to your localhost root as they would a standard website.

When it comes to external access, you'd need to look into [forwarding port 80](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) on your router. 
[You'd also need to ensure apache is set to allow external access.](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,112013,112392#msg-112032)

You can also find free to use domain names [here](http://www.dot.tk/).

Comment: Ah damn well we can only hope right, thanks for your answer